# QTextEdit: get word under the mouse pointer

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qtextedit

I made this `CompileOutput` class, and basically what I want is when I click the word, it emits signal `selectedWord`, and when I hover over words, I want it to emit signal `hoveredWord`.

The `mousePressEvent` works, but `enterEvent` wont work. When I hover over words, nothing happens.

This is my chunk of code:

```
CompileOutput::CompileOutput(QWidget *parent): QTextEdit(parent)
{
    setReadOnly(true);
}
CompileOutput::~CompileOutput()
{
}

void CompileOutput::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
    QTextCursor tc = cursorForPosition ( event->pos());
    tc.select(QTextCursor::LineUnderCursor);
    QString strWord = tc.selectedText();

    if(!strWord.isEmpty())
    {

        emit selectedWord(strWord);
    }
}

void CompileOutput::enterEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QTextCursor tc = cursorForPosition(event->pos());
    tc.select(QTextCursor::LineUnderCursor);
    QString strWord = tc.selectedText();

    qDebug() << strWord;
    if(strWord=="the line i need.")
    {
        emit hoveredWord(); //this signal makes cursor shape change while over right line of text
    }

}
```

Comment: The meaning of `enterEvent` is "the mouse has entered the window". It is delivered once when the mouse passes the threshold of your window. None of the functionality you desire needs to be concerned with that event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

In the constructor add

```
setMouseTracking(true);
```

and then use `mouseMoveEvent` instead of `enterEvent`